# split strings and add them as new row

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
df<-data.frame (fact= c("a,b,c,d","f,g,h,v"), value = c("0,1,0,1" , "0,0,1,0"))
```

This is the data:

```
   fact   value
1 a,b,c,d 0,1,0,1
2 f,g,h,v 0,0,1,0
```

I wish to split it when the **value is 1**. So, my ideal output is:

```
 fact     value

1:  a,b     0,1
2:  c,d     0,1
3: f,g,h    0,0,1
4:  v       0
```

Firstly, I thought I might find a way by using `cut` like:

```
cut(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(df$value), split = ",")), breaks =1)
```

But none of my attempts get close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to split the character vectors for `fact` and `value` in the original data frame by `","` using `strsplit` and then determine the position of the first `"1"` in the split `value`s. Then use this position to determine the split for both `fact` and `value`:

```
sv <- strsplit(df$value,",")
sf <- strsplit(df$fact,",")
pos <- sapply(sv, function(sv) {j <- which(sv=="1"); if (length(j)==0) NA else j[1]})
out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(pos),function(i,sv,sf,pos) {
  if (is.na(pos[i]) || pos[i] == length(sf[[i]])) 
    data.frame(fact=toString(sf[[i]]),value=toString(sv[[i]])) 
  else 
    data.frame(fact=c(toString(sf[[i]][1:pos[i]]),
                      toString(sf[[i]][(pos[i]+1):length(sf[[i]])])),
               value=c(toString(sv[[i]][1:pos[i]]),
                       toString(sv[[i]][(pos[i]+1):length(sv[[i]])])))
  },sv,sf,pos))
##     fact   value
##1    a, b    0, 1
##2    c, d    0, 1
##3 f, g, h 0, 0, 1
##4       v       0
```

This answer assumes that there is a `"1"` in the `value` to split. If there is not or if the `"1"` is at the end of `value`, then that row in `df` is not split in the output.

Answer (score 6):

First we split the strings in `fact` and `value` into separate values and stack them so that each becomes a column of values in a data frame. Now, using `value`, we want each run of zeroes followed by a 1 to become a group. These are the groups of values that we want to paste together at the end. We'll use `dplyr` to operate separately on each group to return the final data frame.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr)  # For map function
library(tidyr)  # For separate_rows function

df %>% 
  separate_rows(fact, value, sep=",") %>%
  mutate(group = lag(cumsum(value == 1), default=0)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(fact = paste(fact, collapse=","),
            value = paste(value, collapse=",")) %>%
  select(-group)     

   fact value 
1   a,b   0,1
2   c,d   0,1
3 f,g,h 0,0,1
4     v     0
```

Answer (score 5):

Another base R attempt:

```
sf <- strsplit(as.character(df$fact), ",")
sv <- strsplit(as.character(df$value), ",")
spl <- lapply(sv, function(x) -rev(cumsum(as.numeric(rev(x)))) )
#[[1]]
#[1] -2 -2 -1 -1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] -1 -1 -1  0

joinfun <- function(x) sapply(unlist(Map(split, x, spl), rec=FALSE), paste, collapse=",")

# to show you what is happening:
#> Map(split, sf, spl)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$`-2`
#[1] "a" "b"
#
#[[1]]$`-1`
#[1] "c" "d"
# 
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$`-1`
#[1] "f" "g" "h"
#
#[[2]]$`0`
#[1] "v"

data.frame(fact  = joinfun(sf), value = joinfun(sv) )
#   fact value
#1   a,b   0,1
#2   c,d   0,1
#3 f,g,h 0,0,1
#4     v     0
```

Answer (score 5):

One data.table approach would be the following. You split each element in `fact` and `value` using `cSplit()` in the `splitstackshape` package. This creates a data.table in a long format. Once you have the result, you create a group variable using `diff()` and `cumsum()` Wherever a difference in `value` is smaller than 0, R creates a new group. Then, you want to apply `paste()` to both `fact` and `value`. You can achieve this using `lapply(.SD ...)`. This is the equivalence of `summarise_at()` in the `dplyr` package.  In the end, you remove the group variable.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)

cSplit(df, splitCols = c("fact", "value"),
       direction = "long", sep = ",") -> temp

temp[, group := cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(value) < 0))][,
       lapply(.SD, function(x){paste(x, collapse = ",")}),
       .SDcols = fact:value,
       by = group][, group :=NULL] -> out

#    fact value
#1:   a,b   0,1
#2:   c,d   0,1
#3: f,g,h 0,0,1
#4:     v     0
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but here is a solution that utilizes `regular expressions` and `tidyverse` functions:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")

library(tidyverse)

dff <- data.frame(fact= c("a,b,c,d","f,g,h,v"), 
                   value = c("0,1,0,1" , "0,0,1,0"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

dff %>% 
  mutate(value = gsub("(?<=1),(?=0)","-", value, perl = T)) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(indices = which(strsplit(value,split="")[[1]]=="-"),
         fact = sprintf("%s-%s", 
                        substr(fact, 0, indices - 1), 
                        substr(fact, indices + 1, nchar(fact)))) %>%
  select(fact, value) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  separate_rows(fact, value, sep = "-")
```

This finds the commas placed right after `1` in the `value` column and then replaces those commas with a dash (`-`). It then gets the indices of those dashes in each row of the `value` column and feeds them to the `fact` column to replace the corresponding commas there with dashes as well. Subsequently, it uses `separate_rows` to split both the `fact` and `value` columns on those dashes.
It should yield the following:

```
#     fact value
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1   a,b   0,1
# 2   c,d   0,1
# 3 f,g,h 0,0,1
# 4     v     0
```

Comment: separate_rows is neat - wasn't aware of that one

Comment: very handy, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Have replaced solution with this simpler one.

No packages are used.  The columns of `df` may be character or factor -- the code converts them to character. `value` entries in the input may contain no ones.  The `fact` and `value` components on the same row of the input should have the same number of comma-separated fields but may have different numbers of fields on different rows.

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, 1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  long <- lapply(x, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ",")))
  g <- -rev(cumsum(rev(long$value == 1)))
  aggregate(long, list(g), paste, collapse = ",")[names(x)]
}))
```

giving:

```
   fact value
1   a,b   0,1
2   c,d   0,1
5 f,g,h 0,0,1
6     v     0
```

`by` calls the anonymous function shown once for each row.  For each row it splits each column by comma giving the long form `long` for that row.  For example, for the iteration that processes first row of `df` the value of `long` is:

```
long <- list(fact = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), value = c("0", "1", "0", "1"))
```

We then calculate a grouping variable `g` for the row.  For example, for the first iteration it equals:

```
g <- c(-2L, -2L, -1L, -1L)
```

Finally we aggregate by `g` pasting the elements from each column having the same group together.  We drop the extra columns that `aggegate` has added.

At the end we `rbind` the data.frames for all rows together.